# Anyone ask support to activate the 'Synchronous Compile During Deploy' aka "Apex Precompiler"?

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have very slow performance on an add on app. Their support said to ask Salesforce support to active the 'Synchronous Compile During Deploy' also known as the Apex Precompiler.

Salesforce support said they activated this feature and I guess performance is a little better. We asked support where this feature is in the UI but no reply.

I can't find anything online about this. Has anyone else used this? any cons to activating this?

Comment: What's the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no feature for customers to interact with. It's a feature configured on the org in the org management utility that internal employees can access. With this feature enabled, it cannot be disabled by customers.

Using this feature will increase deployment time in exchange for faster "first use" execution. Deployments will take slightly longer than before. This is the con for the feature, and it's a fairly small one at that.

The amount of the delay depends on the number and complexity of code units, but likely shouldn't be more than about half a second per class and trigger in most cases.

As far as I can tell, there's no known bugs with this feature, but they are deploying it in phases to make sure there's not a significant impact on deployment times for all orgs.